# Grafana Loki TLS Encryption between Components

Tags: grafana-loki, self-signed-certificate, cacerts

I installed grafana loki in openshift cluster and i would like to secure pod to pod communication using tls encryption. I was able to add Openshift self signed certificate to distributor-gateway. But communication is failing if I add certificate to ingester component. After adding certificate to ingester, Promtail is unable to push logs and grafana unable to pull logs.

Anyone already done this.. Is there any reference document available for the same...

I was able to add Openshift self signed certificate to distributor-gateway. But communication is failing if I add certificate to ingester component. After adding certificate to ingester, Promtail is unable to push logs and grafana unable to pull logs.

Anyone already done this.. Is there any reference document available for the same...